# python- sockets: sending data over different networks

Tags: python-2.7, networking, python-sockets

I want to use this code when the client and the server are on different networks. can pythons sockets do this?

server:

```
import socket
import select
open_client_sockets = []
server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8001))

server_socket.listen(1)
(new_socket1, address1) = server_socket.accept()
open_client_sockets.append(new_socket1)

while True:
    rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select(open_client_sockets, 
open_client_sockets, [])
    for current_socket in rlist:
        data = current_socket.recv(4096)
        if data != '':
            print "given data: ", str(data)
```

client:

```
import socket
import wmi
import time
import sys
ip = 'servers IP'
port = 8001

try:
    my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    my_socket.connect((ip, port))
except:
    print "socket error"

c = wmi.WMI()
disks=[]
for disk in c.Win32_LogicalDisk (DriveType=3):
    data= disk.Caption, "%0.2f%% free" % (100.0 * long (disk.FreeSpace) / long 
(disk.Size))
    disks.append(data)
print str(disks)
data = str(disks)
my_socket.send(data)
```

works just on the same network.

Comment: Welcome to S.O. If you're seeing a message like *"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."* there probably isn't enough information for others to assist you in solving the problem. Please add a brief description of what the code does AND what actually happens when the code is executed - and what you expected to happen instead?

Comment: There isn't anything python specific. As long as the traffic can be routed between the machines, it really doesn't matter where they are (networkily or otherwise).

Comment: Removed extraneous padding text, and please do take the suggestion by @Ageax seriously